# HTML - Is it possible to uncheck all the other checkboxes when you check one checkbox?

Tags: html, css

Basically im building a gallery, with pure css. When I press image1 it will check the checkbox1 and the div1 will appear. I have done that already, the problem is, if I press the image2 the div2 will appear, but if I press the image1 again the div1 will not appear because div2 is in front of it.

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
<label for="toggle1"><a>1</a></label>
<input id="toggle1" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle2"><a>2</a></label>
<input id="toggle2" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle3"><a>3</a></label>
<input id="toggle3" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle4"><a>4</a></label>
<input id="toggle4" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle5"><a>5</a></label>
<input id="toggle5" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle6"><a>6</a></label>
<input id="toggle6" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle7"><a>7</a></label>
<input id="toggle7" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle8"><a>8</a></label>
<input id="toggle8" type="checkbox">
<div class="conteudo1">1</div>
<div class="conteudo2">2</div>
<div class="conteudo3">3</div>
<div class="conteudo4">4</div>
<div class="conteudo5">5</div>
<div class="conteudo6">6</div>
<div class="conteudo7">7</div>
<div class="conteudo8">8</div>
</div>
```

I will not post the css because I didnt found how I can indent the code automatically, but you can see it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/blackice856/3vhCH/1/

Basically what I need is when checkbox1 is checked, uncheck all the other checkboxes, and reapeat that for all the remain checkboxes.

I never liked javascript much, but I just did this with it and It took me like 10 minutes lol, but I still want to know if there is any way of doing it.

Thanks for your time (:

Comment: If you only want one checked at a time then why not use radio buttons?

Comment: I tried with radio buttons, but the only way they can work out is to have only one name for all of them. As you can see in the example I need them to have different names, in order to do diferent actions when checked.

Comment: ops, actually it works out very well! I didn't know that the radio buttons can have a name and an id. They can have different id's and the same name, I just gave them the same name and it's working now! Thanks for your time (: http://jsfiddle.net/blackice856/3vhCH/3/

Comment: @BrunoTavares If you solved your problem, please write an answer instead of a comment. Also not posting your CSS because of not having autoindent is not valid. Get a decent editor ;) (JSFiddle has a tidy up option.) And finally, please avoid tags in question titles or include it more naturally if the question would be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll need to write some Javascript to uncheck the other boxes. HTML itself actually provides similar functionality with radio boxes, as *mu is too short* said